# Image auto-resize in item flex

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have the following code:

```
<ul style="display:flex">
    <li> ..... </li>
    <li> ..... </li>
    <li> ..... </li>
    <li> ..... </li>
    <li> ..... </li>
    <li> ..... </li>
    <li> ..... </li>
    <li> ..... </li>
    <li> ..... </li>
</ul>
```

Each item flex have this css:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    *:not(.bx-viewport) > ul.product_list.grid > li {
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 208px;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 208px;
    flex: 1 1 208px; } }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    *:not(.bx-viewport) > ul.product_list.grid > li {
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 220px;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 220px;
    flex: 1 1 220px; } }
```

The max-width of each item flex is loaded in a javascript function which is executed when the page starts except for the first child of ul which is set like this:

```
li:first-child {
    max-width: 450px !important; 
}

$(window).load(function() {
    $(this).children().removeAttr("style");
    var maxWidth = $(this).children().first().width();
    $(this).children().css("max-width", maxWidth);
});
```

Th problem is that the items appear with one width and then automatically resize to the correct size showing me an effect that I dont want (in the link you can see the error with a gif). Anyone can help to make it appears well?

Comment: Here is the link:    https://gyazo.com/702a55c0ad121c197b64c99238a31e15

Comment: You need to have the items hidden on page load, and then show them after setting correct width

Comment: Please post all relevant code and/or a working demo, so we can reproduce the problem.